How do I handle this error? My App Crashes during internal tests on iOS (React Native - Expo - SDK 51)
I'm experiencing a crash in my React Native Expo app (SDK 51) during internal testing on iOS. The crash occurs when the user performs the following action:
<ButtonFloating fn={ShowAdd} />

const ShowAdd = () => {
navigation.navigate('SolicitudDeFondosAgregar');
};

The app crashes and the log shows the following:
Thread 3 name:
Thread 3 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e070b42c __pthread_kill + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f44aac0c pthread_kill + 268 (pthread.c:1721)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019f5aeba0 abort + 180 (abort.c:118)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001f43c8ca4 abort_message + 132 (abort_message.cpp:78)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001f43b8e5c demangling_terminate_handler() + 348 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:77)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018f4f5e2c _objc_terminate() + 144 (objc-exception.mm:496)
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001f43c8068 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001f43c800c std::terminate() + 108 (cxa_handlers.cpp:88)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f4f5de8 _dispatch_client_callout + 40 (object.m:579)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f4fd400 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 748 (queue.c:3900)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f4fdf30 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 380 (queue.c:3991)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f508cb4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 288 (queue.c:6998)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f508528 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 404 (queue.c:6592)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f44a7934 _pthread_wqthread + 288 (pthread.c:2696)
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f44a40cc start_wqthread + 8 (:-1)

Details:
React Native Version: 0.74.3
Expo SDK Version: 51.0.21
iOS Version:  17.5.1
Device: iPhone 15
My package.json:

 - ...
   
     "dependencies": {
       "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
       "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "8.0.1",
       "@react-native-material/core": "^1.3.7",
       "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.7.5",
       "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
       "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
       "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.0.6",
       "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
       "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
       "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.4.1",
       "axios": "^0.24.0",
       "cors": "^2.8.5",
       "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^5.0.0",
       "expo": "~51.0.21",
       "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
       "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.20",
       "expo-device": "~6.0.2",
       "expo-file-system": "~17.0.1",
       "expo-media-library": "~16.0.4",
       "expo-notifications": "~0.28.10",
       "expo-print": "~13.0.1",
       "expo-sharing": "~12.0.1",
       "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
       "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
       "expo-updates": "~0.25.20",
       "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
       "moment": "^2.29.3",
       "react": "18.2.0",
       "react-dom": "18.2.0",
       "react-native": "0.74.3",
       "react-native-error-boundary": "^1.2.4",
       "react-native-flash-message": "^0.2.1",
       "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
       "react-native-mask-input": "^1.2.0",
       "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
       "react-native-pager-view": "6.3.0",
       "react-native-paper": "^4.11.1",
       "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
       "react-native-reanimated": "^3.10.1",
       "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.5",
       "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
       "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
       "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
       "react-native-woodpicker": "^0.3.17",
       "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
       "react-query": "^3.33.7",
       "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
       "redux": "^4.2.0",
       "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1"   },   "devDependencies": {
       "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
       "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.1",
       "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
       "@types/react-native": "^0.73.0",
       "eslint": "^8.5.0",
       "eslint-config-universe": "^9.0.0",
       "prettier": "^2.5.1",
       "typescript": "5.3.3"   },   "resolutions": {
       "@expo/config-plugins": "^5.0.2",
       "@expo/prebuild-config": "~5.0.3",
       "expo-modules-autolinking": "~1.0.0"   },   "private": true }


I've checked the navigation setup and everything seems to be correctly configured. The issue persists despite multiple tests and debugging attempts. The app is not crashing on Android.
I also installed react-native-reanimated using npm install react-native-reanimated and imported it at the root.
I can't install the latest version of react-native-reanimated: Error: [Reanimated] Mismatch between JavaScript part and native part of Reanimated (3.14.0 vs 3.10.0).
tryied this: GitHub
Still crashing.

Update. The problem was here:
Error: The style property 'shadowOffset' is not supported in a .
If you update all your dependencies, it will work. However, in my case, I had to remove this  and change it to a , which works fine on both iOS and Android.
